# Correct way to insert and query some subscription data in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have a collection of subscription plans which a user can buy them, each subscription has a period in days which is pushed to the `users` collection `subscriptions` array, whenever a new subscription is bought,

I have designed the following schema :

```
{
    username : 'an_string_field',
    password : 'an_string_field',
    //...
    subscriptions : [ //an array field
        {
            'from' => 'some_old_date',
            'to' => 'some_future_data',
            'embeded_subscription' : {
                'duration' : 60,
                'price' : 50000,
                'name' : 'two months plan'
            }
        },
        //...
    ],
}
```

For querying the the user who has a subscription which is not expired (the `to` date has not reached yet) **which one of the following is better**? :

1. `db.users.find({ 'subscriptions.$.to' : { $gt : $currentDate} });`
2. Or adding another field called `expires_at` to the `users` collection, which is updated every time a new subscription is added( It is always equal to the last value of `to` field of the last inserted item in the `subscription` array) and then query with `db.users.find({ 'expires_at' : { $gt : $currentDate }})`

Answer (score 0):

[**`$currentDate`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/currentDate/) is a field update operator so you can't use it with `find` method instead you can create a [**`Date`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Date/#Date) object. Something like this:

```
db.users.find({ your_field_name : { "$gt" : new Date() } })
```